# Change $(px-y)(yp+y)=a^2p$ to Clairaut form, where $p=\frac{dy}{dx}$.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Here $p = \frac{dy}{dx}$.

Due to the factor $(px-y)$, I considered the change of variable $u = \log(\frac{y}{x})$ so that $\frac{du}{dx} = \frac{px-y}{xy}$. But it did not prove to be beneficial.

Any hints or solutions will be appreciated.

Comment: Perhaps $y^2=ux$ works!